# What is the difference between method="post" and type="submit" (HTML)?

Tags: html, forms

Are they completely different things? I don't really get forms yet and many of the guides I found online don't really use type="submit" so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Wasn't https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form under the many guides?

Comment: Sorry! When I wrote this, I was thinking that the type attribute was something else, so it led to some confusion in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` is a form attribute. It specifies the method for requesting the server. It has only two options, either GET or POST. Use GET if your form has not sensitive data, while use POST when you are trying to submit sensitive data like user login. You can refer for more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp#:~:text=The%20method%20attribute%20specifies%20how,URL%20in%20name%2Fvalue%20pairs

`type` is the attribute for input which specifies what the input is gonna be. It's options are text, email, password, checkbox, submit and many more. The type submit tells the input to submit the form when the user clicks the input which has this type on it. Have a look at it https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp.

Example:

```
<form action="to/the/action" method="POST">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user name" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit your form" />
</form>
```

Here is the simple form which tells the browser to show an input of text telling the user to enter user name. The action is the path where you want to send the form data, while type=submit is defining that submit this form when user clicks me.

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you! I asked the question because I was confused by some code that one of my colleagues wrote, but now I've realized the error in what I was thinking.